# How can you easily find block textures in a file folder?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I'm trying to edit some block textures, but I cant seem to find the correct one. each texture has some really long name like "e85904034", and there are hundreds of them. Is there an easier way to find the correct one without having to search the 100's of textures to find the right one??

Comment: Are you talking about texture packs or resource packs? You could look at this guide on the wiki: http://minecraft.gamepedia.com/Tutorials/Creating_a_resource_pack

Comment: You are doing something wrong, its supposed to be something like beacon.png for each block/item

Answer (score 2):

First go to `%appdata%\.minecraft\versions\1.8.4` (or any other version number).
Then copy 1.8.4.jar and change the name to 1.8.4**.zip** (make sure file-extensions are visible).
Open the ZIP-file, and go to `assets\minecraft\textures\blocks`.

Here you'll find all block textures.